# Isuse in binding date value to date input controller - KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, api, knockout.js

I have a date type input controller and trying to bind date value received from api (Json), but it is not binding. able to bind all other text properties/dropdowns etc without any issue.

Api property for date field:

```
assigned_Date: "2022-10-18T00:00:00"
```

Html controller:

```
<input type="date" id="ReceivedDate" class="datepicker form-control-sm" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy" data-bind="value: assigned_Date" placeholder="" />
```

Also tried as,

```
<input type="date" id="ReceivedDate" class="datepicker form-control-sm" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy" data-bind="date: assigned_Date" placeholder="" />
```

Using Knockout JS for MVVM.
All other values are just binding fine except date field. Tried to apply formatting while assigning value, but that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use knockout bindings.
eg:

```
//bind handler
ko.bindingHandlers.date = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, 
        viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var textContent = moment(valueUnwrapped).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
        $(element).val(textContent);
    }
};

//view model
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self=this;
    self.ReceivedDate=ko.observable(new Date());
};
 
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

//html
<input type="text" data-bind="date: ReceivedDate" />
```